# Change div color on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a line of text (a link) within a div. I'd like the div color to change on mouse over the link. I tried various things without success. You can see my current code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/D3TzM/ Note that I'm not necessarily looking for a jquery solution. Tks for your help

CSS

```
.source-title-box a{
    color:#467FD9;
    display:inline-block;   
}
.source-title-box a:hover{
    color:#666666;
}
.source-title-box hover{background:#cb2326;}
```

JS:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes this:

```
.source-title-box a
{
    color:#467FD9;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;    
}
```

to:

```
.source-title-box a
{
    color:#467FD9;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;  
    padding:15px;
}
```

And this:

```
.source-title-box
{
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
}
```

to:

```
.source-title-box
{
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    width:230px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px dotted #666;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D3TzM/7/)**

No JS required.

Answer (score 4):

you can select below a pseudo class like `:hover`. No need for javascript at all for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7bFKq/

```
.source-title-box:hover{
    background-color:#467FD9;

}

.source-title-box:hover a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

​

---

If you must do it with a hover on a, you will need javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wwdb/

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    // .closest will get you to the div regardless of what might
    // be in between. With .parent you get to the absolute parent, which
    // in your case is a span
    $(this).closest('.source-title-box').toggleClass('hover');
});​
```

css is basically the same, just `:hover` to `.hover`

```
.source-title-box.hover{
    background-color:#467FD9;

}

.source-title-box.hover a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: OP's requirements were to change the `div` background upon `a` hover.

Comment: @wanovak why would he want the user to mouse into the link portion of the div before triggering the color change? If that is indeed the request, I would argue that this is superior.

Comment: Don't know, but that's what he asked for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fresheyeball! Interesting non js solution!

Answer (score 2):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pMSz/)

Just look for the closest div, the *immidiate* `.parent()` was a `<span>` tag (which aren't automatically block elements by nature, unless you make them that way).

```
$('.activity-title a').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('hover');
});

$('.activity-title a').on('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the JavaScript you have, and add this CSS class:

```
.hover {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RLjvB/

Comment: Why the down vote? JavaScript is needed to satisfy OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

Greg,
There are 2 points:

1) The jquery .hover() function expects two handlers as argument.
One for handlerin (mouse over) and one for handlerout (on mouse out). Giving only one argument uses the argument as an In-Out handler, i.e the same handler for both mouse events.

2) Make sure that the script that you have written (js) is included at the bottom of the page. ie, just before closing the "body" tag. 

This is because : the html element may not be loading when the script executes.

```
...Your HTML Code...
<script>
    $('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
    });​
</script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm calling the js file containing the script in my head section. Is that OK?

Comment: It is advisable to have it in the bottom of the page.
<br /> 
I usually have 2 .js files : one as header and one as footer.
If you really want to include it in the <head></head> section, you might want to put the jquery code into a document ready function, so that the script executes AFTER the elements load.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ....
    });